# Understanding scoping of event handlers in web workers

Tags: javascript, event-handling, web-worker

Consider the following webworker code from: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

Web page:

```
<button onclick="sayHI()">Say HI</button>
<button onclick="unknownCmd()">Send unknown command</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop worker</button>
<output id="result"></output>

<script>
  function sayHI() {
    worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'start', 'msg': 'Hi'});
  }

  function stop() {
    // worker.terminate() from this script would also stop the worker.
    worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'stop', 'msg': 'Bye'});
  }

  function unknownCmd() {
    worker.postMessage({'cmd': 'foobard', 'msg': '???'});
  }

  var worker = new Worker('doWork2.js');

  worker.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('result').textContent = e.data;
  }, false);
</script>
```

Then in doWork2.js:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var data = e.data;
  switch (data.cmd) {
    case 'start':
      self.postMessage('WORKER STARTED: ' + data.msg);
      break;
    case 'stop':
      self.postMessage('WORKER STOPPED: ' + data.msg +
                       '. (buttons will no longer work)');
      self.close(); // Terminates the worker.
      break;
    default:
      self.postMessage('Unknown command: ' + data.msg);
  };
}, false);
```

So when you click SayHi, the "message" event handler defined in doWork2 picks up the event first. Then it fires another "message" event which is picked up by the handler defined on the main page that prints out the message.

The flow of steps is as such.

1. User clicks button, raises message event.
2. Handler in doWork2 is executed.
3. Handler in doWork2 raises message event
4. Handler on webpage is executed

Please answer the following 2 questions:

**Question 1:**  In step 2. above why is the handler in doWork2 triggered, but not the handler on the page?

**Question 2:** In step 4 after the event is triggered from doWork2 why is the handler on the page executed, but the one in doWork2 isn't recursively executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there are two implementations of postMessage on two different objects.

**Answer to Question 1**

When calling worker.postMessage()

> ...the Worker interface sends a message to the worker's inner scope

And so the message event handler on the page doesn't see it.

**Answer to Question 2**

When calling self.postMesssage , `self` is the worker's global scope, which has an implementation that works as follows:

> sends back information to the thread that spawned it using the
>   `DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope.postMessage` method.

As such it doesn't recursively call itself because the message event is only visible in the thread that spawned it.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage

Answer (score 0):

the reason why doWorks2 event listener gets fired before is because the way javascript is interpreting your code. The code execution in Javascript happens in case of async functions in 2 directions. There is a call stack that has the commands that run in synchronous order or classical sequence and then for async functions there is a message queueing which queues up the events in the order they were added in.

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

Comment: I think the OP is asking why not both event handlers are triggered when a message is dispatched.

Comment: @Titus is correct. I have edited the bottom of the question for clarity on what I don't understand